# Android: Adding a Button to a ScrollView programmatically

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` containing a number of `buttons` and `textviews`.

I wish to `insert a new button` midway (index 3)on the scroll view but get the error, "*ScrollView can host only one direct child*"

Is this not possible?

```
Button b = new Button(this);
scrView.AddView(b,3);
```

????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the sub-views in a layout like `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` then put the layout in the `ScrollView`.  Add your views to the layout rather than the `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't add more then one view in scollview  as you know now "ScrollView can host only one direct child"

you would definalty have a linear layout in scollview  where you would have added other buttons previously so add new one in that......

Comment: how about to remove the child of the scrollview first... and then add the new component into it. :D 

which means, the scrollview still has only ONE single view. right ? @DheereshSingh